# Heroku Deploy Rails App - SProckets error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, heroku

i'm trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails app on Heroku but during the push it seems to be some errors.

when i launch the console command

```
git push heroku master
```

while it's installing the dependences i recive this error.

> Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'angular-route/angular-route'

i've installed the angular-route with Bower:

**Bowerfile**

```
# A sample Bowerfile
# Check out https://github.com/42dev/bower-rails#ruby-dsl-configuration for more options

# asset 'bootstrap'

asset 'angular'
asset 'angular-route'
asset 'bootstrap-sass-official'
# vim: ft=ruby
```

this is my first time i'm developping on heroku so i don't really know what to do in this case. Someone have ever faced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to precompile and commit assets like that:

```
rake assets:precompile
git add .
git commit -m 'Added precompiled assets for Heroku'
git push heroku master
```

Comment: I am not sure precompiling assets on the develop environment is a good practice.

Comment: Thanks Raphael, it actually should be `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`